# A component required a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot multi-module project with Gradle. While running the application i am getting the below error:-

```
Description:

A component required a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder' in your configuration.
```

The project has a root project which has a subproject 'GetAssociationService'

**rootproject - build.gradle**

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
    }

bootJar { enabled = false }

jar { enabled = true }

subprojects {
    group = 'org.qmetech'
    version = '1.0.0'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
    apply plugin: 'java'
}

repositories { mavenCentral ( ) }

ext { set ( 'springCloudVersion' , "Hoxton.SR3" ) }

dependencies {
    testImplementation ( 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test' ) {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage' , module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

ext.libraries = [
        commonlibraries: [ 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.5.RELEASE' ,
                      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-context' ,
                      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws:2.0.1.RELEASE' ,
                      'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j:1.0.0' ,
                      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.2.5.RELEASE' ,
                      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-function-web:1.0.0.RELEASE' ,
                      'org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-thin-layout:1.0.11.RELEASE' ,
                      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.2.5.RELEASE',
                      'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-compiler:2.0.0.RELEASE'] ,
]

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test { useJUnitPlatform ( ) }
ChildProject - build.gradle

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'org.qmetech.GetAssociationService'
}

dependencies {
    dependencies {
        compile libraries.commonlibraries
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package org.qmetech.repository;

import org.qmetech.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> { }
```

**AssociationService.java**

```
package org.qmetech.service;

import org.qmetech.domain.User;
import org.qmetech.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Component
public class AssociationService implements Function<String, List<User>> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public AssociationService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> apply(String uppercaseRequest) {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

The Complete Code can be found here - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/Services

Can Anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the versions from the `org.springframework.boot` and `org.springframework.cloud` dependencies. Those are managed through Spring Boot and the imported BOM. Also make sure you are using the proper Spring Cloud version for your Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and in my case, there was the problem in 'org.springframework.boot' version. I changed my version to 2.1.6 Release. Then the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your pom.xml and make sure you are using the matching version of the Spring boot framework for Spring Cloud.

e.g. For Spring Cloud **Greenwich** you will need Spring boot **2.1.x**

Here is Spring cloud documentation : https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud
Revisit section : **Release Trains**